# Objects cleared when adding subLayer to UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift2, cashapelayer

I'm have using a custom `UIView` class, which has textfields and labels contained within it, courtesy of Storyboard. When the class adds a sublayer within the class, the contained objects on the view disappear, get made transparent or maybe become the same color of the `UIView` background. Is there a property that can be set or a method to employ to ensure that the objects remain visible?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
class viewBorder: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)

        // Create a rect with only 1x rounded corner
        let rectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.TopLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 21.0, height: 21.0))
        let rectLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        rectLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1.5, height: -1.5)
        rectLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
        rectLayer.path = rectPath.CGPath
        rectLayer.fillColor = tintColor.CGColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(rectLayer)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)

    // Create a rect with only 1x rounded corner
    let rectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: UIRectCorner.TopLeft, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 21.0, height: 21.0))
    let rectLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    rectLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1.5, height: -1.5)
    rectLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.6
    rectLayer.path = rectPath.CGPath
    rectLayer.fillColor = tintColor.CGColor
    rectLayer.zPosition = -1 // Added
    self.layer.addSublayer(rectLayer)
}
```

Comment: OMG!!! You are a genius!
Worked perfectly. I have never the 'zPosition' ever mentioned previously!

Comment: If that solved your issue, please up-vote and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks again @Bannings - i've tried to vote, but as i'm new its not showing publicly (apparently?)

Comment: Maybe your reputation is not enough. Whatever, never mind :)